# How can I limit the headphone max volume on OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, audio, sound-volume

So I hurt my ears from excessively loud music last week at work. I'm well aware of the volume down key of course, but I tend to crank it up too much throughout the day without noticing it.

I need a limiter and it needs to be system-wide, since I listen to various other sound sources aside from iTunes. This isn't really an issue on my phone, since I can set a volume limit in the iOS settings.

Is there an equivalent built-in or third-party fix for OS X Lion?

Comment: What's wrong with the default audio settings on your Mac? You can adjust the soundlevel for you entire OS, no?

Comment: I tend to crank it up too much throughout the day without noticing it, ending up hurting my ears. So the same way I can limit the max volume on iOS I want to do it on OS X.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I now got a working solution based on one of the links in Michiel's answer, but let's spell it out more clearly.

What I did was to

1. Download [volimiter](http://www.anoshkin.net/products/mac/volimiter/), a faceless CLI application.
2. Pair it upp with [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/), a launchdaemon manager.
3. Set volimiter to launch on login with preferred setting:

   *volimiter .6*

.6 means 60% of volume.

Works terrific!

Comment: How Exactly did you pair Volimiter and Lingon? I am trying to set a maximum volume for my imac.

Comment: The following setting would limit the volume to 80%. http://i.stack.imgur.com/X3F1X.png

Comment: I ended up wanting a GUI to adjust the volume limit, so I made a volume-limiting status bar app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whisper-volume-limiter/id1438132944

Answer (score 4):

If you're not satisfied with the default audio settings of your Mac (I can increase or decrease the sound for my whole OS with one key), you can try [Hear](http://hear.en.softonic.com/mac). It's an equalizer (and limiter) for the sounds your Mac is producing.

If you really want to limit your sound, I'm afraid there is no app for it right now. I found some other topics however where they asked the same question as you. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/58897/can-i-lock-the-volume-or-disable-the-volume-keys-on-mac-os-x) and [here](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=286655). Basically, it comes down to "use limited external speakers" or "be aware of your sound settings" :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Hear is a bit overkill so I won't try it, but the volimiter CLI app mentioned in the Ars thread was the thing I was looking for. It's not working too well though.

Comment: Working well since I recompiled it for Lion, even though the code uses som deprecated stuff. Win.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is still relevant, I created a little app called [Earsafe](https://earsafe.io). Basically, it's a status menu bar, which lets you limit the volume of the main output of your Mac.

Hope I could help!

Answer (score 0):

We've just released Volume Limiter for Mac, available on the [AppStore](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/volume-limiter/id1478846233?mt=12) as well as [our website](https://volumelimiter.com). (The web version offers a free trial). It has advanced capabilities, including limiting by audio *device*, locking controls for all users on a computer, and 'Mute Mode' (automatic muting based on system events or a user-defined calendar).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a free solution, look no further:

[Limiting your Mac’s volume in 2019](https://medium.com/trabe/limiting-your-macs-volume-in-2019-f314e20408ab)

[Limiting your Mac’s Volume in 2020, an Update](https://medium.com/trabe/limiting-your-macs-volume-in-2020-an-update-8623f99ec69f)